# How to solve $(1-t)^2dy+(ty-y+3)dt=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation: $(1-t)^2dy+(ty-y+3)dt=0$

I tried to use separation method:

$$(1-t)^2dy+y(t-1)dt+3dt=0$$

$$\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dt}{t-1}+\frac{3}{y(t-1)^2}dt=0$$

But in the last fraction I still have $t$ and $y$. I don't know how to separate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

With all these $(1-t)$'s, let $y=\frac z{1-t}$ and it will be very simple.

Comment: Do you mean with all these $(t-1)$'s ?

Comment: @soheil. What is the difference ? Try both.

Comment: Clever substitution . How can I notice these kind of substitutions? should I solve a lot of D.Es to notice them ?

Comment: @soheil. Don't worry ! You will learn the tricks. And take into account that I am almost 80 !!

Comment: Thank you. So you are very experienced at math a real math professor :)

Comment: @soheil. I am just old !

Comment: Just one more question.  It seems you spent a large amount of your time on studying mathematics. aren't you regret or wished to studied something else? ( I ask because I heard mathematic is very very hard so I want to see your point of view)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116723/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-soheil).

Answer (score 2):

Note that your ODE is a [linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions). So we have
$$(1-x)^{2}dy+(xy-y+3)dx=0 \iff \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x-1}=-\frac{3}{(x-1)^{2}}$$
Let the integrant factor $\displaystyle \mu(x)=\exp\left[ \int \frac{1}{x-1}dx \right]=x-1$.
Now, multiply both sides by $\mu$ we have $$(x-1)\frac{dy}{dx}+y=-\frac{3}{x-1}$$
Solving this part $$ \int \frac{d}{dx}((x-1)y)dx=-\int \frac{3}{x-1}dx\implies (x-1)y=-2\ln|x-1|+c $$
So, we have $$\boxed{y=\frac{-3\ln|x-1|+c}{x-1}}$$

---

**Note:** If you have a ODE of the form $$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
So, the integrant factor is the form $$\mu(x)=\exp\left[\int P(x)dx \right]$$
Then, you can multiply both sides of the ODE and you can get $$\frac{d}{dx}(y\mu)=Q(x)\mu(x)dx$$
So, we have $$y\mu(x)=\int Q(x)\mu(x)dx+C$$
So, the general solution for the ODE linear equation of first order is $$\boxed{y(x)=\frac{1}{\mu(x)}\left[\int Q(x)\mu(x)dx+c \right]}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-t)^2dy+(ty-y+3)dt=0$$
$$(1-t)^2dy+y(t-1)dt+3dt=0$$
$$u^2dy+yudu+3du=0$$
$$u(udy+ydu)+3du=0$$
$$d(yu)+\dfrac 3udu=0$$
Where $u=t-1$.
The differential equation is now exact.  Integrate:
$$yu+ 3\ln  |u|=C$$
$$\boxed {y(t-1)+ 3\ln  |t-1|=C}$$